# Globalization for kendo-react-ui/wrappers/grid/

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, kendo-ui-grid

I want to use in React the kendo ui grid wrapper (https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/wrappers/grid/) as it fits our needs more than the normal kendo ui grid.
I just was wondering if there is a way to implement globalization for this grid wrapper.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The messages can be changed by importing the messages file for the desired region.
import '@progress/kendo-ui/js/messages/kendo.messages.region';